# Sql query for insert in grails

Tags: sql, grails

How to execute plain sql in grails . I need to use sql query for inserting new record in database .

How can we achieve this with out using HQL and gorm relations .

thanks

Answer (score 16):

groovy.sql.Sql simplifies the details of doing JDBC queries. In a Grails app you'd use the constructor that takes a DataSource:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
...
class FooService {

   def dataSource
   ...
   def runSqlQuery(...) {
      Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
      sql.executeInsert("insert into ...")
      ...
   }
}
```

See these links for usage tips:

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Tutorial+6+-+Groovy+SQL

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-pg01115.html

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by calling the Hibernate Session.createSQLQuery() method. First you need to get the Hibernate session then use that session to execute SQL. See [this](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2008/07/31/grails-quick-tip-2-getting-access-to-sessionfactory-and-messagesource/) link to see how to get a Hibernate session from your grails app. Then see [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html) link for info on using Hibernate to execute SQL.