# Grails sql queries

Tags: sql, grails

Imagine I have something like this:

```
def example = {
   def temp = ConferenceUser.findAllByUser(User.get(session.user))
   [temp: temp]
}
```

Explaining my problem:
Although dynamic finders are very easy to use and fast to learn, I must replace dynamic finders of my website for sql queries because it is a requirement. As I don't understand SQL that much, my main questions are:

a) I am using an SQLS database, with the drivers and datasource good configured and my website works as it is right now. If I want to replace the "findAllByUser" for an sql statement, should i do something like this:

```
def dataSource
...
def db = new Sql(dataSource)
def temp = db.rows("SELECT ... ")
```

b) And that will work? I mean, the temp object will be a list as it is if I use "findAllByUser", and do I need to open a connection to the database =?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain more about why you would replace findAllByUser with a sql statement, why would that be a requirement? Grails has many different ways to query which are explained in [section 5.4 of the User Guide](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.4%20Querying%20with%20GORM)

Comment: sure. In my project i need to use hibernate and sqls, as im being evaluated on both. If i don't use queries for database search, than the sqls part to be evaluated is none.

Comment: That's odd, considering the point of Grails finders is to make things easier than writing SQL.  But requirements can be really... odd sometimes.

Comment: Sounds like a school project to me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

yes, with grails you can do both plain sql and hql queries.  HQL is 'hibernate query language' and allows you to write sql-like statements, but use your domain classes and properties instead of the table names and column names.  To do an hql query, do something like

```
def UserList = ConferenceUser.executeQuery('from ConferenceUser cu where cu.user = ?', [user]),
```

what you have here is a parameterized query -- executeQuery sees the ? in the hql string and substitutes the arguments in the array that is the second parameter to the method(`[user]` in this case) for you.

See
http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html

and you can see this on how to do sql queries with Grails

[Sql query for insert in grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244811/sql-query-for-insert-in-grails)

Answer (score 25):

With Grails you can use [Dynamic Finders](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.4.1%20Dynamic%20Finders), [Criteria Builders](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.4.2%20Criteria), [Hibernate Query Language (HQL)](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.4.3%20Hibernate%20Query%20Language%20(HQL)), or [Groovy SQL](http://groovy.jmiguel.eu/groovy.codehaus.org/Database+features.html).

To use [Groovy SQL](http://groovy.jmiguel.eu/groovy.codehaus.org/Database+features.html):

1. `import groovy.sql.Sql`
2. Request a reference to the datasource with `def dataSource` or `def sessionFactory` for transactions
3. Create an `Sql` object using `def sql = new Sql(dataSource)` or `def sql = new Sql(sessionFactory.currentSession.connection())`
4. Use [Groovy SQL](http://groovy.jmiguel.eu/groovy.codehaus.org/Database+features.html) as required

Grails will manage the connection to the datasource automatically.

[Sql.rows](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#rows(groovy.lang.GString)) returns a list that can be passed to your [view](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.3%20Models%20and%20Views).

For example:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

class MyController {
    def dataSource
    def example = {
        def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        [ temp: sql.rows("SELECT . . .") ]
    }
}
```

And within a transaction:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

class MyController {
    def sessionFactory
    def example = {
        def sql = new Sql(sessionFactory.currentSession.connection())
        [ temp: sql.rows("SELECT . . .") ]
    }
}
```

I recommend the book [Grails Persistence with GORM and GSQL](http://www.apress.com/java/grails-groovy/9781430219262) for a lot of great tips and techniques.

Comment: thank you for the ebook link, I was looking for a details like this !

Answer (score 3):

**Going Further / Tips**

- **Use Spring beans**

You can make the `groovy.sql.Sql` instance a Spring bean in your Grails application. In `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy` define the Sql bean:

```
// File: grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy

beans = {

    // Create Spring bean for Groovy SQL.
    // groovySql is the name of the bean and can be used
    // for injection.
    sql(groovy.sql.Sql, ref('dataSource'))

}
```

Next inject the Sql instance in your your class.

```
package com.example

import groovy.sql.GroovyRowResult

class CarService {

   // Reference to sql defined in resources.groovy.
   def sql

   List<GroovyRowResult> allCars(final String searchQuery) {
      final String searchString = "%${searchQuery.toUpperCase()}%"

      final String query = '''\
         select id, make, model
         from car
         where ...
         '''

        // Use groovySql bean to execute the query.
        final results = sql.rows(query, search: searchString)
        results
   }
}
```

- **Multiple Datasources**

  adminSql(groovy.sql.Sql, ref("dataSource_admin"))

  userSql(groovy.sql.Sql, ref("dataSource_user"))

and inject the beans

```
def userSql
def adminSql
```

Into the services that need them.

or without injection

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
// ...
// inject the datasource bean
def dataSource_admin

// ...
// in a method
Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource_admin)
```

### Early Grails Version

Looping through GORM result sets in early grails versions can cause needless queries in the middle of template loops. Using groovy SQL can help with this.