# No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost

Tags: mysql, grails, jdbc

I am new to Groovy & Grails, facing this issue. I have been trying to connect mysql to GGTS facing below issue.

GGTS 3.5.1
Grails 2.3.7
Mysql 5.6.19

1. I added dependencies in Buildconfig.groovy, had jar in .m2 repository
   2.Tried adding jar in grails-app/lib
   3.Tried to add @grab, but faced error, "no system classloader'
   4.I am able to use the same url in java/eclipse and able to connect.

Error description displayed in console

```
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
........................................
|Running Grails application
|Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/Hello
....Error 
|
2014-06-15 00:28:44,903 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - SQLException occurred when processing request: [GET] /Hello/book/index
No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/ot. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/ot
    Line | Method
->>  596 | getConnection in java.sql.DriverManager
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    215 | getConnection in     ''
|     12 | index . . . . in hello.BookController
|    200 | doFilter      in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker     in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run           in java.lang.Thread
```

my datasource.groovy

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    dialect = 'org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect'

}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
//    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            username = "root"
            password = "lenovo"
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/ot"

        }
    }
```

Buildconfig.groovy

```
dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime',     'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
            runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.30'
          // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1100-jdbc41'
         }
```

controller

```
def index() {

conn = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ot",
                      "root",
                      "lenovo",
                      "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
                    //  "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver")

conn.rows('select NAME, ROLLNO from student').each{ 
    println "${it.NAME} ${it.ROLLNO}"
```

Please suggest. Thanks for your support in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error is explicitly telling you that you need to add the `mysql` JDBC connector JAR to your classpath.

It is available [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).

Comment: Jar is present in below folders (1) .m2 repository (2) .groovy/lib (3) grails-app/lib...i can see the jar in my  project/properties/java Buildpath as well..

Answer (score 0):

Probably different classloader loads jars and different is used in controller. As proposed here: [Grails sql queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282374/grails-sql-queries) create you Sql instance from injected dataSource instead of Sql.newInstance()

Still you should consider defining a Domain class and access the database with GORM.

hope this helps,
droggo

Comment: ,thanks a lot, i tried using GORM DSL and i am able to save the data in to the table. Below are the changes i did,(1) As it is an existing table, i used static mapping (GORM DSL)..(2) Used dbCreate = Update in Datasource.groovy (3) Instead of Groovy sql statements, i used below GORM statements 'def stud = new Employee()'
  'stud.seqNum = 1 '
  'stud.save(flush:true,failOnError: true)'
  'def findstudent = Employee.list()'

Comment: I am still unable to understand, why groovy sql statments are not working. I will update if i get an answer...

Comment: You can use direct sql, just create your Sql instance based on datasource. If you need to create sql instance without datasource, load it specifying the classloader like that: def driver = Class.forName(driverClassName, false, this.class.classLoader).newInstance();
  def properties = new Properties();
  properties.setProperty('user', username);
  properties.setProperty('password', password);
  driver.connect(dbUrl, properties); This way you specify classloader which should be used and which have access to jdbc lib

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried using dataSource instead of using sql.newInstance. It is working. now i am able to display records using groovy sql. i would like to share what i observed: 'def dataSource' should NOT be inside a method instead it should be at class level. Then only, it seems, groovy will inject. and ofcourse, datasource should have correct properties. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3582387 Hi, I am also facing the same issue. Can you share the corrected code here.