# Cast String Column to Long grails createCriteria

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria

I have a domain class in grails which has a column of string type. Below is the domain class structure.

```
class TravelRequestUpdates{
        updatedAt sqlType:'varchar(40)'

String updatedAt


}
```

I store epoch dates in this column. Using createCriteria i want to perform a between check on this column for long type values but am unable to do so. Is there a way i can store values in this column as String and still perform Long type operation on the values stored. Below is the code for my criteria where i want that the values stored in this table to behave as long type. The dates are not being compared.

```
              def criteriaObj = TravelRequestUpdates.createCriteria()

def travelToShow = criteriaObj.get{

                    @Formula("cast(updatedAt as NUMBER(20,0))")
                    long tempUpdatedAt

                    tr{
                      eq('id',g.id)
                    }
                    and{
                      between(tempUpdatedAt, startTimeReport.time, endTimeReport.time)
                    }
                    and{
                      newStatus{
                        eq('id',completedTravelsStatus.id)
                      }
                    }
                  }
```

I want to generate a query like the one below. The below query gives me the desired result.

```
SELECT *
FROM travel_request_updates
WHERE tr_id = '439'
AND updated_at BETWEEN ('1478016321000') AND('1478189121000')
AND new_status_id = '4'
```

Comment: values stored in this table to behave `as long` type... as you said it.. and{
                      between(tempUpdatedAt `as Long`, startTimeReport.time, endTimeReport.time)
                    }

Comment: Not working .... it is giving me a NullPointerException ... although as a work around i put both greater than and less than clause .... the problem with that is that the grater than clause works fine on its own but the less than clause doesnt seem to work ...

Not working

`and{ge("updatedAt", String.valueOf(startTimeReport.time))} and{le("updatedAt", String.valueOf(endTimeReport.time))}`

Not Working

`and{le("updatedAt", String.valueOf(endTimeReport.time))}`

Working

`and{ge("updatedAt", String.valueOf(startTimeReport.time)) }`

Answer (score 2):

Sorry my comment won't solve it since I think that is your input range.

There are a few options

1. Enable a transient object of Long in your domain class that converts the underlying string to Long so:

   ```
   class TravelRequestUpdates{
    String updatedAt
    Long myConversion

    static transients = [ 'myConversion' ]


    Long getMyConverion() {
     return (this.updatedAt as Long)
    }
   }
   ```
2. Would be to write it in something like `HQL` and possibly cast the object:

   ```
   String query = "FROM travelRequestUpdates
   WHERE tr_id = :myid
   AND cast (updatedAt as Long) BETWEEN (:input1) AND(:input2)
   AND newSatusId = :status"
   def myParams=[status: '4', input1: 1478016321000L, input2: 1478189121000L, myId: 439L]
   def myList = TravelRequestUpdates.execute(query,myParams,[readonly:true])
   ```

`L` has cast them as Long values you can Declare long values if you prefer, alternatively you can run a [sql query directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282374/grails-sql-queries) if all of that fails.

Comment: I made a very silly mistake due to which this was not working i had a SimpleDateFormat variable to parse the dates passed from the view to the controller the epoch time generated was incorrect which is why the between clause was not working in the first place Below is the mistake i was making`SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MM-yyyy")Date tempStart = df.parse(startTime)Date tempEnd = df.parse(endTime)`The above is wrong as the DD should be lower case ... `SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")Date tempStart = df.parse(startTime) Date tempEnd = df.parse(endTime)`

Comment: Thanks for your help anyways @vahid